# handleRequest of CmisWebServicesServlet is not getting called and it is giving 'Cannot get CSRF manager!' error

Tags: java, server, cmis, opencmis, tomcat10

Actually we have extended Open CMIS code for our product and recently we have upgraded our product for Tomcat 10. When we call RepositoryService it is giving below error:

```js
java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
[21/07/23 01:11:23:023 IST] ERROR org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.server.impl.webservices.AbstractService: Cannot get CSRF manager!
org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.exceptions.CmisRuntimeException: Cannot get CSRF manager!
        at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.server.impl.webservices.AbstractService.checkCsrfToken(AbstractService.java:166) ~[chemistry-opencmis-server-bindings-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
        at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.server.impl.webservices.AbstractService.getServiceForRepositoryInfo(AbstractService.java:187) ~[chemistry-opencmis-server-bindings-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
        at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.server.impl.webservices.RepositoryService.getRepositories(RepositoryService.java:65) ~[chemistry-opencmis-server-bindings-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[?:?]
```

What I am suspecting is that handleRequest present in CmisWebServicesServlet is not getting called that's why we are not able to set attributes in request and it is giving CSRF related error.

```js
public void handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException {
        // set CMIS version and CSRF Manager
        request.setAttribute(CMIS_VERSION, cmisVersion);
        request.setAttribute(CSRF_MANAGER, csrfManager);
```

Anyone can tell me what could be cause for this error;

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by removing sun-jaxws.xml file from WEB-INF. I also removed WSContextListener from web.xml.

The issue was with CMISWebServicesServlet. Earlier in Open CMIS 0.13.0 CMISWebServicesServlet was extending WSServlet that's why we had this WS configuration in our WEB-INF. But now that is not needed in Open CMIS 1.1.0.